# java.util.Vector cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList error when json is parsed in java

Tags: java, json, codeigniter, codenameone

I want to use arraylist instead of vector since ArrayList gives better performance etc. However the code works using vector as well. I dont understand when i use json_encode, sometimes it can be parsed in arraylist and sometimes in vector. What makes difference on casting the json parsed value to vector and arraylist? Is it from model/controller(CI used here) or i hav to do smth different in java json parser?

codeIgniter controller:

```
$data = $this->member->view_members();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

CI model:

```
$queries = $this->db->get('members');
return $queries->result();
```

json:

```
[{  "id": "1",
    "name": "Magalamind Industries",
    "tableGroup": "Birgunj  rising round table 20",
    "email": "birgunj123@gmail.com",
    "position": "Senior Member",
    "address": "Birgunj",
    "phn": "9876543234",
    "date": "2016-05-03 15:53:51",
    "active": "1"},
 {  "id": "2",
    "name": "Ram kumar Sharma",
    "tableGroup": "Lalitpur round table 5",
    "email": "ram@gmail.com",
    "position": "Recent Member",
    "address": "Patandhoka, lalitpur",
    "phn": "9876567890",
    "date": "2016-05-03 15:53:51",
    "active": "1"}]
```

java json parse with error msg: java.util.Vector cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

```
ConnectionRequest connectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest() {    
    @Override
    protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
        JSONParser jSONParser = new JSONParser();
        Map<String,Object> parsedData = jSONParser.parse(new InputStreamReader(input));
        response = (ArrayList) parsedData.get("root"); //error msg: java.util.Vector cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    }   
    .........
}
```

Comment: Well, it's a `Vector`, and the two types aren't related. Make `response` a `Vector`, or copy its contents into an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Or even better, use Jackson or Gson to parse it out fully.

Comment: @AndyTurner I've already mentioned above i can make response vector and work but sometimes i can work directly in arraylistm. That's why i am asking if i can do smth here?

Comment: @beck so do the other thing I suggested.

Comment: @chrylis i am using it in java plugin 'codename one' for mobile devices so i hav no idea if it support Jackson. Thanky anyway i'll check it out

Comment: @AndyTurner i dont get it how can i copy the contents in arraylist?

Comment: `new ArrayList<Object>(someVector)` will create a new `ArrayList` with the same elements that are in `someVector`. I wouldn't bother with this unless you know that using `Vector` is giving you performance problems due to its methods being synchronized. I strongly doubt that this is the case, however.

Comment: @TedHopp thanks. However the main reason i have posted the question is that i always have the same json code and java parser but sometime it can be parsed directly to arraylist and sometime it must be vector first and then vector to arraylist. Is there some reasons behind?

Comment: A lot of different libraries have a  `JSONParser`. Which one are you using?

Comment: Actually it is the default java jsonParser provided by codenameone sdk for mobile app development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

```
jSONParser.parse(new InputStreamReader(input));
```

is the old parsing method (notice it is deprecated in the javadocs), it uses Hashtables and Vectors.

You need to use the

```
jSONParser.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));
```

Which uses HashMap and ArrayList